# Vba - match command where character is included

Tags: vba, excel

i have the following vba code:

```
Function countX(area_x As String, area_w As String)

Dim Nr As Integer, count_x As Integer, Col_Ind
Dim temp_area As Range

For Nr = 10 To 1 Step -1

With Worksheets(CStr(Nr))

    If WorksheetFunction.CountIf(.Range(area_w), "*w*") > 0 Then

        'Find "w" in area_w
        Col_Ind = WorksheetFunction.Match("w", .Range(area_w))

        MsgBox (Col_Ind)

        'Reset numbers of "x" in area_w
        Set temp_area = .Range(.Cells(9, 4).Offset(0, Col_Ind), .Cells(9, 9))
        count_x = count_x + WorksheetFunction.CountIf(temp_area, "*x*")
        Exit For
    Else

        count_x = count_x + WorksheetFunction.CountIf(.Range(area_x), "*x*")

    End If

End With

Next
countX = count_x
End Function
```

I have 10 sheets - all with the same structure.

- D9 - I9 => the user shell set a "x" (if necessary)
- K9 - P9 => the user Shell set a "w" (if necessary)

I have another sheet (the same worksheet) as a overview. On dies page i would like to see all counted "x" of the 10 sheets.

The difficult part was:

- only "x" after a setted "w" should be counted.

Example:
in sheet 8 was setted a "w".
now should be count only "x" from page 8 (after w) to 10.

Picture example:

[image]

the result of counted "x" will be "2", because there are 2 "x" after the setted "w"

and here is the Problem.
it only works, if the user setted a "w". but "w/r" or "r/w", etc. doesn't work.

and for this i need a solution :)

Comment: Is that a typo? `arear_w` at the beginning and `area_w` in the middle? also no output is set: `Function countW` at the beginning but no `countW =`.... cannot imagine that this ever worked...

Comment: i have updated my code. there was a mistake. the code above is not the complete code, only a part of this. but this is my problem part

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just 3 ways how you could it do:

```
Public Function countW(area_w As String)
  With Application.Caller.Parent.Range(area_w)
    Set countW = .Find("w*", .Cells(1, 1), xlValues, xlWhole, , xlNext, 0)
    If .Rows.Count - 1 Then countW = countW.Row - .Row + 1 Else countW = countW.Column - .Column + 1
  End With
End Function
```

or

```
Public Function countW(area_w As String)
  With Application.Caller.Parent.Range(area_w)
    countW = Application.Match("w", Application.Transpose(.Parent.Evaluate("INDEX(LEFT(" & area_w & "),)")), 0)
  End With
End Function
```

or

```
Public Function countW(area_w As String)
  countW = Application.Match("w*", Application.Caller.Parent.Range(area_w), 0)
End Function
```

**EDIT**
In my opinion your "change" looks way more like a new question than a small update (and also should be asked as a new one). Still I will give you a solution this time.

```
Public Function countX(area_x As String, area_w As String) As Long
  Dim i As Long, to_offset As Variant, x_rng As Range
  For i = 1 To 10 'upper loop for worksheets
    With Worksheets(i)
      to_offset = Application.Match("*w*", .Range(area_w), 0)
      If IsNumeric(to_offset) Then 'run only if there is a "w" found
        If .Range(area_x).Columns.Count > 1 Then 'just one row
          Set x_rng = Intersect(.Range(area_x), .Range(area_x).Offset(0, to_offset))
        Else 'just one column
          Set x_rng = Intersect(.Range(area_x), .Range(area_x).Offset(to_offset))
        End If
        If .Range(area_x).Cells.Count > to_offset Then 'not running if the "last" cell has the was as we cout only "after" it
          countX = countX + Application.CountIf(x_rng, "*x*")
        End If
      End If
    End With
  Next
End Function
```

If doing it the way it looks for all worksheets, also this code will do:

```
Public Function countX(area_x As String, area_w As String) As Long
  Dim ws
  For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
    If IsNumeric(Application.Match("*w*", Intersect(ws.Range(area_w), ws.Range(area_w).Offset(, -1)), 0)) Then
      countX = countX + Application.CountIf(Intersect(ws.Range(area_x), ws.Range(area_x).Offset(0, Application.Match("*w*", ws.Range(area_w), 0))), "*x*")
    End If
  Next
End Function
```

Comment: i updated my first post completly with my whole code and situation. i hope somebody can help :)

Answer (score 1):

Maybe not the best solution (and I don't have time to try it myself right now), but one way of doing this would be to loop over the cells and use InStr(cell, "w") > 0 on each cell...

Comment: `InStr(cell, "w") > 0` also would be true for `"xwv"` which should not be the case...